# How to generate dynamic form based on my json response from URL in java framework (JSF)?

Tags: javascript, json, jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to create dynamic form based on my json data in my browser,I know this is possible from using some javascript library like inputex etc but I am not expert in using javascript,I have made application using jsf 2.0 , I wanted some solution in Java, some thing like android , where we can easily create any type of UI dynamically, here is my json from which I need to create form , I can modify this response for any help as this json is also made by me.

```
  {
surveyQuestions: [3]
0:  {
choice: [3]
0:  "choice1"
1:  "choice2"
2:  "choice3"
-
date: "2013-10-30T00:00:00+05:30"
q_id: "10"
question: "Question 1?"
questionType: "single_choice"
surveyType: "first_survey"
versionid: "1.1"
}-
1:  {
choice: [5]
0:  "choice0"
1:  "choice1"
2:  "choice2"
3:  "choice3"
4:  "All of Above"
-
date: "2013-10-30T00:00:00+05:30"
q_id: "11"
question: "Question 2?"
questionType: "multiple_choice"
surveyType: "first_survey"
versionid: "1.1"
}-
2:  {
choice: [4]
0:  "choice1"
1:  "choice2"
2:  "choice3"
3:  "choice4"
-
date: "2013-10-30T00:00:00+05:30"
q_id: "12"
question: "Question 3?"
questionType: "single_choice"
surveyType: "first_survey"
versionid: "1.1"
}-
-
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript, read that json in your backing bean / controller and work with that.

You should transform that json in an appropiate list of objects that you can use in java. If you need a library to work with json in java, look at the answers of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/338586/1073063

Comment: which framework should I use so that I can easily convert the list of object to its appropriate UI ? Please help me by showing the working code for this.

Comment: @focode We solve specific problems in stackoverflow, we don't design solutions. Learn to use JSF, search google for examples and try a few things. If you have specific problems, you can post questions in stackoverflow then.